# filter function is giving different result for functions & lambda expressions, Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to filter even numbers from a list by using filter function of Python

```
def evenNum(num):
    if num % 2 == 0 :
        return num

list1 = [i for i in range(-10 , 10)]

print (list1)
# [-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

print(list(filter(evenNum,list1)))
# [-10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 2, 4, 6, 8]

print(list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0 , list1)))
# [-10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Why 0 is missing when an defined function is used?

Comment: Your `evenNum()` function returns a "falsy" value (zero) when given a zero as input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `filter` leaves only those elements for which the provided method returns `True`. Your method:

```
def evenNum(num):
    if num % 2 == 0 :
        return num
```

Does not return `bool`, but either `None` which is translated to `False` or `num` which is also translated to `bool(num)`. And `bool(0) == False`, so your filter method won't pass 0. You need to modify it to return bool value:

```
def evenNum(num):
    return num % 2 == 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Your functions don't return the same thing. Your lambda correctly returns a boolean. But your other function returns the number itself; and 0 is boolean False.

To get the correct result you should return a bool:

```
def evenNum(num):
    if num % 2 == 0 :
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns the number if it's even. Otherwise, it returns None.

Your lambda returns True if the number is even, False otherwise.

If you filter on what's returned by each of these, your function will exclude 0, because 0 evaluates as false. The lambda will return True for 0, so it will be included.